# Moveit gets stuck after planning

Tags: c++, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I currently want to send a joint-space goal to my 6DOF arm. move_point is a pointer to my move_group. The command comes from a GUI I wrote and the callback looks like this:

```
void goal_joint_callback(mybot::joint_command msg){
     ROS_INFO("debug1");
     std::vector<double> joint_group_positions(6);
     joint_group_positions[0] = msg.joint1;  // radians
     joint_group_positions[1] = msg.joint2;
     joint_group_positions[2] = msg.joint3; 
     joint_group_positions[3] = msg.joint4; 
     joint_group_positions[4] = msg.joint5;
     joint_group_positions[5] = msg.joint6;
     ROS_INFO("debug2");
     move_point->setJointValueTarget(joint_group_positions);
     ROS_INFO("debug3");
     bool success = move_point->plan(*current_plan);
     ROS_INFO("debug4");
     ROS_INFO_NAMED("tutorial", "Visualizing plan 2 (joint space goal) %s", success ? "" : "FAILED");
 }
```

The goal gets visualized quite nice in rviz and until then everything looks ok.

In my output terminal I can see "debug 1,2,3" but not "debug 4": I am also unable to send additional goals after the first one. I cant really tell why, because the same lines of code (bool success = move_point->plan(*current_plan);) do work at another place with the cartesian path.

Thank you in advance,

Felix

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265294/moveit-gets-stuck-after-planning/) by [Felix_N](https://answers.ros.org/users/30725/felix_n/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2017-07-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey Felix_N,

my first guess is a problem with your control flow.

The plan function calls the ROS action provided by the `move_group` node and waits for the result.
See [here](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/blob/kinetic-devel/moveit_ros/planning_interface/move_group_interface/src/move_group_interface.cpp#L812).

If you are already in a callback and don't have an additional ROS spinner, the action client will never receive the message it is waiting for.

Try to create (and start) a `ros::AsyncSpinner` in your main scope before `ros::spin()`.

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-03**:
Probably related: #q264748 (see the comments).

**Comment by [Felix_N](https://answers.ros.org/users/30725/felix_n/) on 2017-07-05**:
You got it. I have a spinner everywhere else but forgot it at that point. Thanks.

**Comment by [amcelroy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30626/amcelroy/) on 2017-07-27**:
Thanks, this was my issue as well, started and stopped an async spinner in my callback did the trick

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-28**:
@Felix_N and @amcelroy: please note what @v4hn writes:

> create [..] a `ros::AsyncSpinner` **in your main scope**

main scope != in your callback.

I would refrain from doing any spinning in callbacks. Only in very specific circumstances should this be done.

**Comment by [amcelroy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30626/amcelroy/) on 2017-07-28**:
@Felix_N and @gvdhoorn - I do have an asyncspinner in my the main function that registers the callback, but for some reason I still had this exact same problem.
My workflow in main is:

- ros::init
- allocate asyncspinner
- start the spinner
- register callback / do stuff
- ros::waitForShutdown

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-07-29**:
Notice that `waitForShutdown` does *not* spin, so if your asyncspinner does not spin with more than one thread you will still see the problem.

**Comment by [amcelroy](https://answers.ros.org/users/30626/amcelroy/) on 2017-07-29**:
Wow, ok, thanks so much. Creating AscynSpinner with 2 threads did the trick and allowed for the removal of the aysncspinner in the callback. Is it possible for myself or someone higher up to make a note of this on the Callbacks wiki? http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-07-29**:
Oh, I didn't know such a documentation actually exists :)
I added a short comment to the section. Please have a look.